# foreach loop and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, foreach, xamarin

I am using this code:

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Results);
// Create your application here
string[] listResults = Intent.GetStringArrayExtra ("resultData");
LinearLayout linear = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.linear);
TextView resultsPaste = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.resultsPaste);

foreach(string item in listResults) {
    resultsPaste.Text += item;
};
```

And I am receiving `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` next to the `foreach`. I have researched and can't find anything on it.

Why am I receiving the error?

Comment: That would happen if `listResults` is null. Perhaps `Intent.GetStringArrayExtra` isn't working as you expect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3):

listResults, resultsPaste or both are null. Put a breakpoint before foreach and check the variables.

Comment: Helped me out. So simple, yet so easy to stumble over something small like that.

Comment: Yes data is sometimes null in the wild. What is your recommended fix? Would an if statement to check for nulls be advised here?